# Catching a warning with Error Boundary (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

Noob here, not too sure about component configuration, so I ended up with an routing warning error (i.e. "No routes matched location "/play") which is displayed as a warning.

I'm tying to convert this into an error, and then hand it over to ErrorBoundary. It gets converted, but it's not being caught, so ErrorBoundary doesn't activate. What am I doing wrong?

```
//coverting the warning --No routes matched location "/play"-- into an error
console.warn = function (...args) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    throw new Error(args[0]);
  }, 0);
};

class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
  state = { hasError: false };
  static getDerivedStateFromError() {
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    console.error("Error boundary caugh an error", error, info);
  }
```

Convert a warning into an error and handle it with ErrorBoundary

Comment: Did you wrap your component with error boundaries? check the example here https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

Comment: Yes, I followed the tutorial to the letter

Answer (score 0):

According to [react documents](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)

> Error boundaries do not catch errors for asynchronous code (e.g. setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame callbacks).

Asynchronous errors can be handled using [unhandledrejection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event) event.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function ErrorBoundary({ children }) {
  const captureReject = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(error);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', captureReject);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('unhandledrejection', captureReject);
    }
  }, []);

  return children;
}
```

You can use it like this.